# Is there a limit on number of recipients of message sent using Gmail API?

Tags: gmail-api

We recently sent an email using GMail API. In the email, there are 270 recipients in BCC. We got the following error from googleapi: Error 400: Too many recipients, invalidArgument,

My question is: Is there a limit on the number of recipients in a message sent using Gmail API? if it is the case, how big is it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

According to [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) you have a limit of 100 recipients per message.

> Recipients per message sent via SMTP (by POP or IMAP users) or the Gmail API
>   Addresses in the To, Cc, and Bcc fields of a single email. Includes email sent using smtp-relay.gmail.com or smtp.gmail.com*
>
> 100

Not sure if this limitation is only for third parties (such as yourself) or in general. The terms of use for the API clearly state that one should not abuse the API and sending a mail to almost 300 people at the same time might be considered an attempt to spam.

As an alternative you can split your recipients count into chunks that fit into the limit and send multiple mails to cover them all. In your case you would have to send 3 mails: 2x100 and 1x70.

Don't forget about the note (above the table in the document I've linked):

> Sending limits are different if your organization uses the SMTP relay service to route outgoing mail through Google. Instead, go to sending limits for the SMTP relay service.